# ng-click not firing from anchor tag using directive

Tags: angularjs

I've written a directive that return a ul with one list item along with the function that action should fire. The action does not fire, and I see no error in the log.
Here's my code:

```
    localizer_module.directive('utilityMenu', function(){

    return {
        scope: {
            action: '&'
          },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template:
        "<ul ><li style='font-size:12px; color:#FFF;'><a href ng-click='action()'>Hello, world</a></li></ul>",

    }; 
});

localizer_module.writelog = function(){

    console.log("Called!");
};
```

If I add an onclick="alert('fired')", I get the alert. What am I doing wrong with my directive?
Thanks

Comment: Please show the usage of your directive as well.  Ideally post a plunkr to show the problem in action.  As is the formatting is hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough here to help you. I need a plunker or something so I can help figure out why it isn't working. Here's some things to check though:

Make sure that the parent scope that contains your directive has the function assigned to it that you are calling via the action attribute.

so if you're doing this:

```
<utility-menu action="submit()"></utility-menu>
```

than your controller needs to have this:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.submit = function() {
     alert('yes');
  }
}
```

Comment: The parent scope is what I was missing. Thanks